# Meu site não carrega todos os scripts, ele está pesado? como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde

Meu site não carrega todos os scripts, ele está pesado? como resolver?

Exemplo de imagem que não carrega:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no object inspector do chrome aparece as seguintes mensagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Site:https://natupot.000webhostapp.com/index.html

Comment: Segundo o erro, você precisa carregar o conteúdo sobre HTTPS. Os elementos que foram apontados, experimente trocar HTTP por HTTPS.

Comment: Qual o link da imagem que não carrega?

Comment: Mostre a linha 1 do seu código

Answer (score 1):

Por segurança, no seu caso, uma resposta `https` está sendo servida, então você precisa que a requisição tambem seja feita `https`, e não está sendo(http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php)